# how to add a data to webservice with special characters?

Tags: android

i am trying to add a two strings to the web service its working fine when i send through browser and it returns "inserted successfully"
but when i run my application its displaying an error as E/Responce(17407): Illegal character in query at index 74: http://purple2.com/beerbro/addgroupon.php?userid=27&data=100001190851696,1|100001640732983,1|100002430763518,1|100002332633534,1|100000549596039,1|1375802933,1|1587585991,1|1569563632,1|100000132426450,1|100004296815391,1|1519195978,1
,
 i think there is a problem with "|" this but i am not able to find the solution
here is the code
for(int i=0; i

```
data=data+friendid[i]+","+status[i]+"|";
          data.replaceAll("","%20");
        if(i==0){

        }
        else if(i==10)
        {
         String res=UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl(DataUrls.addfriendsurl+"?userid="+usid+"&data="+data.substring(0,data.length()-1));

         Log.e("res",DataUrls.addfriendsurl+"?userid="+usid+"&data="+data.substring(0,data.length()-1));
         Log.e("Responce",res);
         data="";

        }
```

Comment: *solved :-  the actual problem is with "|" this character this should not be used ,i changed this in cms to other character now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

if '|' is the problem then use URLEncoder and encode the String

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("100001190851696,1|100001640732983,1|100002430763518,1|100002332633534,1|100000549596039,1|1375802933,1|1587585991,1|1569563632,1|100000132426450,1|100004296815391,1|1519195978");
String mainURL = "http://purple2.com/beerbro/addgroupon.php?userid=27&data="+data;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: then the problem is not with '|' can you give more details